# how to supress connection error warnings

Tags: php

I am using the following to make a connection (code works) but if `$url` is invalid, it will display the connection error warning to the user which isn't very user friendly.. I would like to surpress the connection errors warnings and display my own warning

> "Failed to establish a connection. Check the host you entered is valid."

instead.

```
$ctx = stream_context_create( array("ssl" => $ssloptions) );
$result = stream_socket_client("ssl://$url:443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

if($result == false) {
    echo "Failed to establish a connection. Check the host you entered is valid.";
    }
```

Here is the current output shown when a user enters an invalid host or if the connection failed:

> Warning:  stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.  in C:\xampp\htdocs\labs\getcertdetails\get_cert2.php on line 27
>
> Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://www.epson.co.au:443 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type
>   was found. ) in C:\xampp\htdocs\labs\getcertdetails\get_cert2.php on
>   line 27
>
> Failed to establish a connection. Check the host you entered is valid.

Comment: its just the variable to pass the host name i.e. `$url = 'www.domain.com';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `@$result = stream_socket_client("ssl://$url:443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);`

Comment: wow just adding the @ symbol at the beginning made it work -- what does the @ do ?

Comment: exactly what you want to do, supress warnings. :)